# UnicodeEncodeError when typing Chinese into url

Tags: python

```
import urllib.request
import bs4
key_word = input('What is the good you are searching for?')
price_low_limit = input('What are the lowest price restrictions?')
price_high_limit = input('What are the highest price restrictions?')
url_jd = 'https://search.jd.com/search?keyword={}&enc=utf-8&qrst=2&rt=1&stop=1&vt=2&wq={}&ev=exprice_{}-{}%5E&uc=0#J_searchWrap'.format(key_word, key_word, price_low_limit, price_high_limit)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url_jd)
text = response.read().decode()
html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
total_item_j = []
for information in html.find_all('div', {'class': "gl-i-wrap"}):
    for a in information.find_all('a', limit=1):
        a_title = a['title']
        a_href = a['href']
    for prices in information.find_all('i', limit=1):
        a = prices.text
        item_j = {}
        item_j['price'] = float(a)
        item_j['name'] = a_title
        item_j['url'] = a_href
        total_item_j.append(item_j)
print(total_item_j)
```

This is a project I do in the school. I want to use this program to extract prices of goods I search. Currently, this code can work for English Input in python 3.7. However, if I search the good in Chinese, for example '巧克力' (Chocolate), it would turn out a Unicode Encode Error. Please, help me out.

Comment: Did you encode it first then decode it?

Comment: How can I use this code to run an input of 'key_word' in Chinese?

Comment: No, I did not. I just want to put the key_word as a string into the url.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to ensure your string is encoded correctly. If you change key_word to:

```
key_word = u'巧克力'.encode('utf-8')
```

You'll find it works fine.

So your code would look like:

```
import urllib.request
import bs4
key_word = input('What is the good you are searching for?')
key_word = key_word.encode('utf-8') 
...
```

More on unicode in python [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the stack trace, you'll see something like:

```
# Non-ASCII characters should have been eliminated earlier
--> 983         self._output(request.encode('ascii'))
```

ASCII encoding will fail for the characters in your `key_word` variable.
They should be URL-escaped first. Do that with:

```
key_word = urllib.parse.quote_plus(key_word)
```

And then prepare the `url_jd` string.